# spring mybatis - Failed to parse mapping resource

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I made a boardContentMap in clubMapper.xml, but I don't know why they can't find it.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\workspace_springProject.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\controller\WEB-INF\classes\mappers\clubMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'boardContentMap'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: boardContentMap

**clubMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.joinus.mapper.ClubMapper">


<resultMap type="MembersVo" id="membersMap">
   <id property="member_no" column="member_no"/>
   <id property="member_email" column="member_email"/>
   <id property="member_pass" column="member_pass"/>
   <id property="member_name" column="member_name"/>
   <id property="member_tel" column="member_tel"/>
   <id property="member_image" column="member_image"/>
   <id property="member_regdate" column="member_regdate"/>
   <id property="member_updatedate" column="member_updatedate"/>
   <id property="member_authority" column="member_authority"/>
   <id property="member_signup_type" column="member_signup_type"/>
   <id property="member_status" column="member_status"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="ClubsVo" id="clubsMap">
   <id property="club_no" column="club_no"/>
   <id property="club_name" column="club_name"/>
   <id property="club_capacity" column="club_capacity"/>
   <id property="club_content" column="club_content"/>
   <id property="club_image" column="club_image"/>
   <id property="club_regdate" column="club_regdate"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="ClubBoardsVo" id="clubBoardsMap">
    <id property="club_board_no" column="club_board_no"/>
    <id property="club_no" column="club_no"/>
    <id property="board_type_no" column="board_type_no"/>
    <id property="member_no" column="member_no"/>
    <id property="club_board_title" column="club_board_title"/>
    <id property="club_board_content" column="club_board_content"/>
    <id property="club_board_image" column="club_board_image"/>
    <id property="club_board_date" column="club_board_date"/>
    <id property="club_board_updatedate" column="club_board_updatedate"/>
    <id property="club_board_like" column="club_board_like"/>
    <id property="club_board_commentcnt" column="club_board_commentcnt"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="BoardTotalBean" id="boardListMap">
    <collection property="membersVo" resultMap="membersMap"/>
    <collection property="clubBoardsVo" resultMap="clubBoardsMap" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="BoardTotalBean" id="boardContentMap">
    <collection property="clubBoardsVo" resultMap="clubBoardsMap"></collection>
    <collection property="clubsVo" resultMap="clubsMap"></collection>
    <collection property="membersVo" resultMap="membersMap"></collection>
</resultMap>


<select id="getBoardList" resultMap="boardListMap">
    select b.club_board_no, m.member_name, m.member_image, b.club_board_title, b.club_board_content, b.club_board_image, b.club_board_date, b.club_board_updatedate, b.club_board_like, b.club_board_commentcnt
    from club_boards b
    join members m
        on (b.member_no = m.member_no)
    where b.club_no = #{club_no} and b.board_type_no = #{board_type_no}
    order by club_board_no desc
</select>


<select id="getBoardContent" resultType="boardContentMap">
    select c.club_name, b.board_type_no, m.member_name, m.member_image, b.club_board_title, b.club_board_content, b.club_board_image, b.club_board_date, b.club_board_updatedate 
    from club_boards b
    join clubs c
        on (b.club_no = c.club_no)
    join members m
        on (b.member_no = m.member_no)
    where club_board_no = #{club_board_no}
</select>


</mapper>
```

**BoardTotalBean.java**

```
package com.joinus.domain;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class BoardTotalBean {

private MembersVo membersVo;
private ClubBoardsVo clubBoardsVo;
private ClubsVo clubsVo;

}
```

Comment: I think that should be `resultMap="boardContentMap"`

Comment: Oh my god!!
Thank you so much. Why did I miss this? Thank you!!!!!!!!!!